# New translations don't show up automatically in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, localization

I've added a few new translations to my iOS 8 project. If I now let my app run on my simulator, the new translations won't be shown.

After I have changed the language to German and back to English, the new translations appeared.

Is this a normal behavior? What happens if the user download the update from the store?

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing, mind you, but I've seen similar problems only with simulator and never with App Store update over an earlier app version.

Xcode and simulator seem to cache resource files, such as graphics and localisation, and sometimes fail to notice when they have been updated.

You can **reset simulator** from menu: "iOS Simulator" - "Reset Contents and Settings...", but that will wipe away everything. However now you should get all the latest resource files (which Xcode thinks are the latest).

Sometimes it's enough just to **ask Xcode to clean the project** and rebuild everything. Note that Xcode menu: Product - Clean is not enough. You have to do Product - Clean Build Folder (press ALT button while menu is open). Sometimes you have to go to menu: Window - Organiser - Projects and delete **Derived Data** folder.

Answer (score 0):

A clean doesn't work. A reset does neither. What worked was that I've exported the translations, changed something and import it afterwards.

If doing this way, iPhone and simulators both will see the updates.

Answer (score 0):

I test all translations on the device. The simulator is not reliable with respect to translations.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in the iOS 8.x simulator runtimes related to CFPreferences, so your app is likely stuck on en_US as its language rather than respecting your settings.  Please give the latest iOS 8.3 beta simulator runtime a try as it addresses some of these issues.